# How do you find the pair of witnesses in Big-O notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

In this example my textbook provides: 
$4n^2+21n+100$   is   $O(n^2)$.

What I do not understand is that the book says the witnesses to this relationship is C = 8, K = 9. How did they come up with those number?

The book kind of gives an answer to how they came up with C = 8:

Suppose $n \ge 0$

$4n^2+21n+100 \le 4n^2+24n+100$ (Yes, the left is $21n$ and the right is $24n$) 
$\le 4(n^2 + 6n + 25)$
$\le 8n^2$

I have no idea how they got these numbers, could someone explain this to me. 
I also understand that if there is one pair of witnesses to a relationship, there exists an infinite number of witnesses therefore what is another pair that would be valid for this relationship? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Simpler: for every $n\ge1$, $1\le n\le n^2$ hence $4n^2+21n+100 \le4n^2+21n^2+100n^2=125n^2$ hence $4n^2+21n+100 =O(n^2)$. I guess you would say that the witnesses are $C = 125$ and $K = 1$.

Comment: @Did Based on your explanation would that mean that the witness for another relationship $x^4+9^3+4(x)+7$ is $O(x^4)$ can be $C = 21$ and $K = 1$? Since $x^4 + 9x^4 + 4x^4 + 7x^4 = 21x^4$.

Comment: If you mean $x^4+9x^3+4x+7$, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is that they try to get some inequality of the form :

$$4n^2+21n+100 \leq Cn^2$$ to prove that this function is $O(n^2)$ .

The inequality they use :

$$4(n^2+6n+25) \leq 8n^2$$ is equivalent with : $$6n+25 \leq n^2$$ which is true for every $n \geq 9$  .

It doesn't matter which $C$ you choose as long as the inequality is true from some point on , for $n \geq n_0$  .

You could choose $C=1000$ to make things even simpler , as obviously :

$$4(n^2+6n+25) \leq 4(n^2+6n^2+25n^2)=128n^2 < 1000n^2$$ for every $n \geq 1$

You could also choose $n=4+ \epsilon$ for some very small $\epsilon$ and the inequality would be :

$$24n+100 \leq \epsilon n^2$$ which is true from some point on but for small numbers it fails .

They have thus chosen a bigger constant to make the inequality simpler to verify .

Comment: How did you get from $4(n^2+6n+25) \le 8n^2$ to $6n+5 \le n^2$?

Comment: @WinstonNguyễn It should be $6n+25$ but the point still holds .